# Failed to debunk an argument against a simple conditional probabilty question

Tags: conditional-probability

During family festivities last Christmas, someone read out the following question from a puzzle book:

> **I have two children, who aren't both boys. How probable is it that they are both girls?**

Using some very shaky stats, I worked out that:

P(Both Girls | Not Both Boys)

= P(Both Girls) / [1 - P(Both Boys)]

= (1/2 x 1/2) / (1 - 1/2 x 1/2)

= 1/3

(Which was also the answer in the book)

However, my brother in-law contested this and said (effectively):

> Well, if they're not both boys, then one of them is guaranteed to be a
> girl. In which case, it's just 50/50.

Frankly, I couldn't argue against his reasoning (then or still).

**How could I have responded?**

Thanks!

Comment: At least one is a girl, but you don't know which, so either child 1 or child 2 could be the girl, or both. With uniform probability you then have a $\frac{1}{3}$ chance.

Comment: I ask this question at all parties.  Those who know I have a boy and a girl answer "1".  Those who are acquainted only with the girl answer "1/2." ;-)  Facetiousness aside, the point is that the question is unanswerable until a definite probability model is put in evidence.  Arguments ensue when different parties implicitly adopt different models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four possibilities to start with, one is excluded

<s>boy,boy</s>
boy,girl
girl,boy
girl,girl

Since you know that option boy,boy is not one of them, you are left with 3 options. There is now only one event of interest "girl,girl" out of three, so the probability is 1/3.

In this case, it *appears* that the brother-in-law is considering the combinations, not permutations. Hence, the 50/50 suggestion.

Comment: Seeing it laid out like this is really useful... Effectively, my brother-in-law is counting GB and BG as the same outcome... I _think_ this is why he is saying it's 50/50. **Could the question have been interpreted in such a way that this is reasonable?**

Comment: @RMills330 Yes, he is counting the number of combinations rather than the number of permutations (order is important). That is, there is only one way to select 1 boy and 1 girl, however there are 2 combinations in which you can order them: BG and GB. He failed to account for these, if the questions had been stated differently this could be true, but not in the current state.

Comment: I think you've nailed it... It's where he's (effectively) considering combinations not permutations. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/176202/frans-rodenburg answer is correct, in that there are two ways of having a boy and a girl: BG and GB.

Your stats look sound to me.  Assuming the probability of having a boy is equal to that of having a girl, $P(G)=P(B)=1/2$, then the probability of having two boys is equal to that of having two girls $P(GG)=P(BB)=1/4$, and the probability of having one of each is the complement of the sum: $P(BG or GB)=1-1/4-1/4=1/2$.  The proba of having no boys is then $P(GG or GB or BG)=1/2+1/4=3/4$.  Using Bayes' theorem, the probability of having two girls given there are not two boys is: $$P(GG|not BB) = P(not BB|GG) \frac{P(GG)}{P(not BB)}= \frac{1/4}{3/4} = 1/3$$
since the probability of not having two boys given there are two girls is 1.